Remove 'false' from json before converting to xml
I'm converting a JSON file from jsonrpc to XML.
But the API gives fields with false values when the field is not filled in, e.g. street2
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "code": 200,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "Somebody",
            "street": "21 golfcountry",
            "street2": false,
            "city": "Amsterdam",
            "custom_value_1": "false",
            "custom_value_2": "true",
            "custom_value_3": "sometimes",
            "is_company": false
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "name": "Somebody else",
            "street": "27 golfcountry",
            "street2": "sub lane 21",
            "city": "Amsterdam",
            "custom_value_1": "",
            "custom_value_2": "10 %",
            "custom_value_3": "always",
            "is_company": true
        }
    ]
}

so the XML resolves in
<street2>false</street2>

and
<street2>sub lane 21</street2>

I want to remove those false fields before converting.
In this case 'false' can be an custom text value, but can be a logic.

Remove: "street2": false
Leave:  "custom_value_1": "false"
Remove: "is_company": false

How can i remove those false values in 1 + 3
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);


What have you've tried? Where are you stuck?

the API gives fields with false values when the field is not filled - that seems like a bug, FWIW, but perhaps there's nothing you can do about that?

Try a custom converter

since Newtonsoft doesn't seem to provide a custom serializer solution to inject into DeserializeXmlNode and since that seem to be a requirement that you can't circumvent by using a different serializer, maybe you could just process the XmlDocument just after it was deserialized by removing the nodes you wish to remove. But you were not clear about the exact conditions. You cited false values in general and some specific property names.. but you were not strict about that so it's hard to propose a solid answer here

What should happen when there is a real boolean field set to false?

@500-InternalServerError The app ODOO fills the fields with false if the field is not filled in the database......

Is there a public API documentation for ODOO we can have a look at?

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/external_api.html

You can use XSLT to remove not needed XML elements as a post-processing step.

A piece of c# code that removes those tags would also be useful, if you have it.

Please edit your question, and add your XML sample. After that I will post an answer.

Off-the-shelf JSON-to-XML converters very rarely produce exactly the output you want. You typically need to preprocess the JSON or postprocess the XML. XSLT is the tool for the job!

The linked API says it can already deliver XML-RPC. Any reason not using that directly but translating from JSON-RPC to XML?

@Ralf my program is running fully on JSON but a part of code not, still running in XML.

Sounds like this API is fundamentally broken if it's putting false where there should be a string or null

I fixed it, creating my own routine.

Here is a solution that is using XSLT to remove not needed XML elements as a post-processing step.
It is using a so called Identity Transform XSLT pattern.
The 2nd XSLT template removing two XML elements if their textual value is false.
Input XML
<root>
    <jsonrpc>2.0</jsonrpc>
    <code>200</code>
    <result>
        <id>32</id>
        <name>Somebody</name>
        <street2>false</street2>
        <city>Amsterdam</city>
        <is_company>false</is_company>
    </result>
        <result>
        <id>38</id>
        <name>Somebody else</name>
        <street2>sub lane 21</street2>
        <city>Amsterdam</city>
    </result>
</root>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
               encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!--Identity transform-->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="street2 | is_company [text()='false']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<root>
  <jsonrpc>2.0</jsonrpc>
  <code>200</code>
  <result>
    <id>32</id>
    <name>Somebody</name>
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
  </result>
  <result>
    <id>38</id>
    <name>Somebody else</name>
    <street2>sub lane 21</street2>
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
  </result>
</root>

c#
void Main()
{
   const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
   const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\process.xslt";
   const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\output.xml";

   try
   {
      XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

      using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
      {
         XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

         XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
         settings.IndentChars = "\t";
         // to remove BOM
         settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

         using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
         {
            xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
            result.Close();
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been generated.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}


You mean after DeserializeXmlNode you can't distinguish "false" from false as the quotes are gone in XML and you still have a problem before this shown solution kicks in?

Let's wait for the OP feedback. The XSLT is very easy to adjust, to accommodate any need.

I updated the answer to go just after two specific XML elements: street2 and  is_company. As I mentioned earlier, it is better to edit the question, and provide an XML sample.

Maybe the problem is more that the XML no longer shows what is logic and what is text, since quotes are gone in XML. So i am more looking for JSON to remove them before quotes are gone. Removing the data in XML is no problem at all (XLST etc.)
